# why is my mesh fully lit from all angles with no lights in the scene?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, lighting

I am playing around with materials in blender cycles, and for some reason my mesh is brightly lit with no lamps in the scene. ambient occlusion is off and I tried restarting blender. what is going on here?
[image]

Comment: hello, please show your Shader Editor, maybe you're using an Emission node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **World Background** itself (grey) is also a source of lighting. To remove its influence, change the *Color* to black in the box on the right, or set the *Strength* to 0

[image: Background]

This can also happen if you forget to connect your material to a shader before connecting to the material output:

[image: Backlight2]

This example just uses a Diffuse BSDF - note that despite the object no longer "glowing", it is still lit, even though there is no light in the scene - that is from the World Background as mentioned at the top:

[image: Backlight2]

Comment: Thanks! that worked